# oracle procedure ussing Host() command

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am having a problem using `host()` command in oracle procedure. 
I have written very simple oracle code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 

run_command(command_i IN VARCHAR2)

IS
  l_message  VARCHAR2 (100);

BEGIN

  l_message  := 'cmd ' || command_i;

  host(l_message); 

END run_command;
```

when `host(l_message);` is eliminated works fine.

Whats the problem and is there anyway to create a routine which uses `host()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HOST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm#SQPUG047) command is only available in SQL*Plus and not from PL/SQL.

You can use Java stored procedure to call call OS commands. Oracle released a [white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf) on calling OS commands from within PL/SQL back in 2008 but there's plenty of other stuff out there (including [Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql.php), which is quite good)

Comment: Reference:   http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_operating_system_os_command_oracle.htm --> this OS call from PLSQL does not work - on Oracle 12c, others not sure.

Comment: That is a very old page @Peter. It recommends using packages that were deprecated ~9 years ago. I'd more strongly advocate against calling the OS from Oracle than I didn't five years ago

Answer (score 0):

Another clunky, but non-Java way would be to create DBMS_SCHEDULER ad-hoc EXECUTABLE job which is your HOST command (e.g. `ls` ), and then execute the job.

Note these run on the database server, not on your remote/local client.